# How do I know what the root python file/module run is?

Tags: python-3.x

So I have some code which seems to be specific to live vs test environments.  To bypass live datasets in the environments, I was going to put in a conditional block.

I can normally run the application with `python3 app` or `python3 -m app` but if i want to run it with pytest for example: `python3 -m pytest` i want to be able to differentiate whether pytest is being used or not.

I was thinking there might be some insight from the `__name__` property but when referencing it, it was not showing me anything related to pytest, but instead elsewhere.  Am i missing something?  Is there a different keyword i should be using to check against?

the `sys` module, i dont necessarily think would do the trick if it were to just check the argv for something specific, as part of me thinks that:  `'pytest' in sys.argv` seems kinda hacky but i guess doable.  I was just thinking there was a better way of determining whether or not I was running pytest

Answer (score 0):

Im not necessarily sure if this is the best answer, but leveraging the `sys` import you can take a look at the imported modules.  As such you can see if pytest is one of those modules.

So, instead of looking at system arguments, you could likely take a look at the modules running at the point in time:

```
if 'pytest' in sys.modules:
  pass
```

Can allow you to see if it is loaded in memory.